# mongodb/mongoose findOneandUpdate how to get index and delete object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am having event object, which have comments, and comments have likes array.
What I currently can do is to add like to comments array of event object.

My schema looks similar to this:

```
  creator: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  comments: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      likes: [
        {
          user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And my current add like to comments function looks like this:

```
  commentLike: async (req, res) => {
    console.log('working', req.params.id, req.params.idas, req.params.commentID);
    Events.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.idas, comments: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.commentID } } },
      { $push: { 'comments.$.likes': { user: req.params.id } } },
      (result) => {
        res.json(result);
      }
    );
  }
```

Params: idas- event._id, commentID: comment id, id: user._id

The problem is that i can add endless likes since, I have no logical operation to check if user already liked it, and im really strugling, in this findoneandupdate function to do that. But thats on problem, another thing what I want to do is unlike comment, and Im having atrouble at figuring it out, on how to get user index from likes array so i can slice that index out, currently my function is looking like this:

```
  deleteLike: async (req, res) => {
    console.log('working', req.params.id, req.params.idas, req.params.commentID);
    Events.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.idas, comments: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.commentID } } },
      {
        $push: {
          'comments.$.likes': {
            $each: [],
            $slice: 0 //there instead of 0 should be user index
          }
        }
      },
      (result) => {
        res.json(result);
      }
    );
  }
```

On this function im also using findoneandupdate function, which is probably not a good idea? Was trying to use findandremove, but it removes entire event object.

Comment: Maybe you can save likes as just user_id and whenever someone's unliking return a new filtered array by that user_id. I think it might be simpler

Comment: Can you follow up more on this? I am not sure if I'm getting you

Comment: If you save your likes as a simple array of user_ids e.g.  ```[1,2,3...]```, then, assuming a user is logged in when unliking, you can filter is the likes array e.g. ```likesArray = likesArray.filter(id => user.id !== id)``` and then when finding that Event, update use ```$set{'comment.likes': likesArray} ```. Hope it makes sense and helps

Comment: managed to "pull it off "using pull operator

Answer (score 1):

So i managed to to it, by using pull operator.
Working delete comment like fuction

```
  deleteLike: async (req, res) => {
    console.log('working', req.params.id, req.params.idas, req.params.commentID);
    Events.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.idas, comments: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.commentID } } },
      {
        $pull: { 'comments.$.likes': { user: req.params.id } }
      },
      (result) => {
        res.json(result);
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Cool, forgot about ```$pull```